# Making GWT JSNI code legal to Checkstyle's TrailingComment metric

Tags: java, gwt, checkstyle, jsni

Checkstyle's TrailingComment module detects the following as an invalid trailing comment in line 001:

```
000 private native void doSomething()/*-{
001    .. javascript code here ..
002 }-*/
```

Which is of course right, but I want to configure [legalComment](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html) to ignore them. This is a regular expression, and I expected "`-\{`" would do the trick. It does not... did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `\(\)s*\/\*` (or `\(\)s*\/\*$`)?

Comment: I think that'd be the format, not the legalCOmment, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the `legalComment` pattern is not applied to multiline comments. So you must solve your problem in the `format` property.

One way of doing that would be to allow trailing comments for native methods, like so:

```xml
<module name="TrailingComment">
    <property name="format" value="^(?:.+?\bnative\b.+?|[\s\}\);]*)$"/>
</module>
```

Comment: That's a very nice regex, thanks so much! It only does not cover the case where the method name + parameter length is so long that the line is wrapped, in which case, of course, "native" is not present. Because there's no way to identify a JSNI method other than by `native` (and that's not even perfect) and because this rule is not applied to multiline comments, I think your solution's the best possible, so I'm sticking to that. Thanks!